# Automatically fill empty area between polygons if within certain distance using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon

Suppose there are two polygons that are closer than 10m to each other. I would like to either combine those two polygons or create a new polygon that fills the empty area between them.

Comment: Try the tool called Integrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a [Geodatabase topology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/creating-a-map-topology.htm)
2. Use rule ["Must not have gaps"](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm):

> This rule requires that there are no voids within a single polygon or
>   between adjacent polygons. All polygons must form a continuous
>   surface. An error will always exist on the perimeter of the surface.
>   You can either ignore this error or mark it as an exception. Use this
>   rule on data that must completely cover an area. For example, soil
>   polygons cannot include gaps or form voids—they must cover an entire
>   area.

3. [Validate topology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/validating-a-geodatabase-topology.htm)
4. Find and [fix topology errors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/fixing-topology-errors.htm)

[This cheat sheet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/pdf/topology_rules_poster.pdf) shows all topology rules very clear.

---

## Workflow:

1. Create geodatabase and add layers (I created a simple one):
   [image]
2. This is my example layer with polygons (50 x 50 m), see distance between polygons:

[image]

3. Create topology with cluster tolerance equal to 10 meters:
   [image]
4. Validate it:
   [image]
5. Results:
   [image]

Comment: Will that rule allow me to specify a distance from which a void is not allowed? In my case I need polygons that are further than a certain distance to still be as separate polygons. thanks for the quick response

Comment: @zarf no problem. Check my update